# Avoiding "Stop Script?" Dialog in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, angularjs

I have some computation-heavy Javascript code that I want to run as part of my application.  I understand that I'm sharing resources with the UI thread so I've made the UI very responsive by breaking it into chunks and using Angular's $timeout to execute each small chunk at a time.  This works fine, except in Internet Explorer 8, where I consistently get the prompt "Stop running this script?"

How do I understand IE8's threshold for "too much script" so that I can work around it?  I'm returning control to the main thread often enough for the application to be responsive and problem-free in other browsers.  I don't have any infinite loop situations or anything.

Comment: Keep reducing the amount of work per-iteration until the error stops?

Comment: Can you show us the code? Maybe IE does something different with the `$timeout`s

Comment: @Bergi: No, `$timeout` is just a wrapper around `setTimeout` with some exception handling stuff: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$timeout

Comment: I have had success with this issue using `setTimeout` so can you `$timeout`with smaller chunks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE8's concept of a "slow script" is based on the number of operations it performs, rather than any set period of time like some other browsers. From [KB175500](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/175500):

> As of Internet Explorer 4.0...the time-out is no longer a fixed value based on Windows messages. Internet Explorer now tracks the total number of executed script statements and resets the value each time that a new script execution is started...

So if you do a lot of quickly-executing script statements, you can still hit the limit in a somewhat short period of time.

Debugging and working around this is a matter of reducing the amount of work you do on each iteration (each `$timeout` call, in your case) until the problem goes away (since, sadly, IE8 [doesn't](http://caniuse.com/#feat=webworkers) support [web workers](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/)).

Answer (score -1):

I have not tried it, but I suggest that instead of using timeout, you post an event and catch it to process the next chunk, etc... Hope that can trick IE, please let us know.

Comment: This isn't an answer, it's speculation. (And wrong, at that -- `$timeout` wraps `setTimeout`, which resets the limit IE uses.)